# Sparx System Enterprise Architect - Unbinding to Source Control

Tags: enterprise-architect

I currently use EA connected to TFS as source control repository to manage the models, however I now have a need to stop using source control.

I've searched but only seem to be able to find resources on working with TFS, but I cannot seem to be able to find an easy way to unbind the model from TFS, so any help is appreciated.

Cheers
Ash

Answer (score 1):

In Enterprise Architect, when you right click on a package in the project browser there is a "Package Control" option. Drill down to "Configure". This will open the Package Control Options. There should be a check box there that says "Control Package". This should unbind your model from TFS.

You may have to play around with source code locations (code files for each element in your model) as they will now not be housed in the TFS repository.

I hope this helps.